# SSH internet through Connect bot

Tags: internet, ssh

Is it possible to forward all traffic from internet app over connect bot forwarded port?

Answer (score 4):

It sure is possible if the app you want to send through the tunnel allows you to specify the host and port to connect to.

e.g. if you use a remote desktop client you could use connectbot to ssh into your home server, set up a tunnel on the appropriate port, and then use the rdp client to connect to localhost in order to use that tunnel.

Cyanogenmod does have a proxy setting available under Settings > Wireless & Network > Proxy Settings. So if you were to run a proxy server on your target computer, you could indeed set it up to proxy through the tunnel.

So let's say I've got an ssh server at example.com. Internally I installed Squidcache (a proxy server) on 192.168.0.101.

In connectbot I'd set up a tunnel like this:

```
Nickname: HTTP Proxy
Type: Local
Source Port: 3128
Destination: 192.168.0.101:3128
```

Then in cyanogenmod's proxy settings I'd set it up like this:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3128
Enable Proxy on wifi: Yes (Or no, whatever you prefer)
```