# RDP client that can use an SSH tunnel created by ConnectBot?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I want to reach my home PC with RDP but I want to do it in an SSH tunnel because of security reasons. Are there any RDP clients for Android that can be set to use the SSH tunnel created by ConnectBot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SSH internet through Connect bot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/ssh-internet-through-connect-bot/6632#6632)

Answer to this question describes how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I just released a free app on Google Play called aRDP Free, which supports seamless RDP over SSH. Here is the link to it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freeaRDP

I also have an app which supports seamless VNC over SSH in Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freebVNC

Comment: Thanks for your work! Is it open-source? If so, you might want to consider to include it in http://f-droid.org

Comment: yes, i could connect through aRDP via ssh to my xrdp server.

Comment: i will try this from my chromebook too